# MySQL Subquery managing different cases

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I'm having a problem writing a complex query.

This is the database structure:

**collections**

```
__________________________
| id   | title           | 
--------------------------
| 123  | With Group      |
--------------------------
| 321  | No groups       |         
-------------------------
```

**collection_categories**

```
___________________________________
| id | id_collection | id_category|
-----------------------------------
| 1  | 123           | 32         |
-----------------------------------
```

**groups_categories**

```
_______________________________
| id | id_category | id_group |
-------------------------------
| 2 | 32           | 11       |
-------------------------------
```

**users_groups**

```
___________________________
| id | id_user | id_group |
---------------------------
| 1  | 345     | 11       |
---------------------------
| 2  | 674     | 12       |
---------------------------
```

The final result is that:
For the collections with id 123 -> check all tables to understand if user can access to it, basically in this example id_user 346 can access to collection with id 123, id_user 674 can't access to it.
Both of them can access to collection with id 321.

There is a way how can I manage this cases both from MySQL without do some additional check in the backend code?
Because in my tests, when I do the check, in case of id_user 674 I can't get results. (with a Join query, users_groups does not have elements that match with groups_categories).

Thanks guys, I'll add here more informations as I do more tries.

EDIT 1:
Rows can be missing inside the tables and there is no need to check groups_categories and collection_categories, it's enough to check the absence of one or more rows inside collection_categories with the id_collection, I can just show up collections.
Example: SELECT * FROM collections WHERE (id=123 OR id=321) AND other things to check here
In this case depended from users I'll get different outputs. I can get both or one of two.

ID_USER 674 can't access to collection with ID 123 because that collection has a category that is inside a group that not contains user 674.

EDIT 2:
I was trying to add a NOT EXISTS AND EXISTS concatenated with an OR operator into the query:

- NOT EXISTS -> to check if that id_collection is not present inside the groups_categories
- EXISTS -> to check if id_collection is present inside the groups_categories and if the id_user is inside users_groups where users_group.id_group = groups_categories.id_group

Comment: *Both of them can access to collection with id 321.* Why? I do not see the chain which makes any user related to this collection...

Comment: Exactly, because it's not mandatory to setup a specific group, it's an additional configuration but not mandatory, and if not setup there is no needs to check it

Comment: *and if not setup there is no needs to check it* What is "not setup"? the related row absence in `collection_categories` only? in `collection_categories` or `groups_categories`?

Comment: Meaning that the row can be missing inside the tables and in that case there is no need to check groups_categories and collection_categories, it's enough to check the absence of one or more rows inside collection_categories with the id_collection I'm getting to just show up the collections I get. 
Example: SELECT * FROM collections WHERE (id=123 OR id=321) AND other things to check here
In this case depended from users I'll get different outputs. I can get both or one of two.

Comment: *Meaning that the row can be missing inside the tables and in that case there is no need to check groups_categories and collection_categories, it's enough to check the absence of one or more rows inside collection_categories with the id_collection* If so then... you tell that "id_user 674 can't access" - but where you know from that the relatoin is absent and not was missing?

Comment: Anycase - create query which checks existing permission chain, create query which selects collections without related rows in collection_categories, and UNION ALL them.

Comment: ID_USER 674 can't access to collection with ID 123 because that collection has a category that is inside a group that not contains user 674. I've added these details on the main question. I just want to avoid make different queries for the case and instead I want to do only one query that manage all these cases.